# GCD function for C

Tags: c

Q 1. Problem 5 (evenly divisible) I tried the brute force method but it took time, so I referred few sites and found this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    while (b != 0)
    {
        a %= b;
        a ^= b;
        b ^= a;
        a ^= b;
    }

    return a;
}

int lcm(int a, int b)
{
    return a / gcd(a, b) * b;
}

int main()
{
    int res = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        res = lcm(res, i);
    }

    printf("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

This is very simple but I don't understand how function "gcd" works; can somebody please help me understand the logic. (I know it returns the GCD of 2 numbers but why so many operations?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). You'll also learn more that way -- and your goal is to learn C, right? :) Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Google searching for 'Sieve Eratosthenes' leads to many sites that explain it.  If your search engine doesn't, it's time to switch.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is designed around the concept of one question per post. You've clearly asked three totally different questions (one about problem 7, one about problem 5, and one about the Sieve of Erasosthenes). Please [edit] your question and remove two of them; you can write separate posts and ask each of the others separately there. While you're editing, you can also change the subject to something useful. "Project Euler doubts" is meaningless for future searches here. The [help] and [about] pages have more information about how SO works if you need it. Thanks. :-)

Comment: That's funny code for the GCD.  The 3 xor operations swap `a` and `b`, but it's easier to write: `int gcd(int x, int y)
{
 int r;

 if (x <= 0 || y <= 0)
  return(0);

 while ((r = x % y) != 0)
 {
  x = y;
  y = r;
 }
 return(y);
}` Yes, it uses a local variable which the code you found does not, but that's not a dramatic cost.  I note that there are at least two other questions about Euler Project 5 ([Euler Project 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645301/project-euler-5?rq=1) and [Euler Project 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473060/project-euler-exercise-5-approach?rq=1)).

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#C

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To your second question: The GCD function uses [Euclid's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). It computes `A mod B`, then swaps A and B with an [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). A more readable version might look like this:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int temp;
    while (b != 0)
    {
        temp = a % b;

        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This problem can also be solved in a very clean way with recursion:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int remainder = a % b;

    if (remainder == 0) {
        return b;
    }

    return gcd(b, remainder);
}
```

Comment: A recursive solution that can be written as a simple loop is bad use of recursion.

Comment: this is very clean solution and more understandable than the accepted answer. plus one though !

Comment: @ChrisTaylor any recursive function can be written as a loop, do you mean that we should not use recursion at all?

Comment: @NikitaHismatov - not at all, but just using recursion for the sake of recursion is where I see a problem.  There are problems that are well suited to recursion, and it makes sense to use, then there are to problems that other than educational value when learning about recursion will often not be implemented that way for production systems.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Actually that would be fine for production, since it is a tail recursion and will be reduced to a loop by any decent optimizing compiler. The fact that the code is very clean and readily verifiable might even make it preferable for a production system.

Answer (score 1):

The GCD computation in C :

```c
int gcd(int a, int b){
    if (a && b) for(;(a %= b) && (b %= a););
    return a | b;
}
```

The absolute value computation :

```c
#include <limits.h>
unsigned int abso(int v){
    const int mask = v >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
    return (v + mask) ^ mask;
}
```

Comment: Don't write your own `abs`. Why not just use the standard library `abs`?

Answer (score 0):

**I executed this statements for GCD :**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
   int l, s,r;

   printf("\n\tEnter value : ");
   scanf("%d %d",&l,&s);

  while(l%s!=0){
    r=l%s;
    l=s;
    s=r;
  }
  printf("\n\tGCD = %d",s);
  getch();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using a bit of recursion and Objective-C

```
-(int)euclid:(int)numA numB:(int)numB
{
    if (numB == 0)
        return numA;
    else
        return ([self euclid:numB numB:numA % numB]);
}
```