# ERROR in GCD calculation using Function in C language

Tags: c

this code is showing some syntactical errors I can't find out where it is, may be it is in the gcd function. here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)

int gcd(int,int);
{
     int a,b, temp;
     printf("Enter the value of a");
     scanf("%d",&a);
     printf("Enter the value of b");
     scanf("%d",&b);
     if (b>=a)
     {
         int temp;
         temp=b;
         b=a;
         a=temp;

     }
     elseif(b!=0)
     {
         gcd(a,b);
         printf("The Gcd of the numbere is %d",gcd(a,b));
     }
     else
     {
         printf("The GCD of %d %d is %d:",a,b,a);
     }
     getch();

     return 0;
}

int gcd(int a,int b)
{
    int g;
    while(b!=0)
    {
               g=a%b;
               a=b;
               b=g;
               return g;
    }

}
```

I would be thankful if you point out my errors and explain with the correct code.

Comment: Why have you tagged this C++?

Comment: The error message includes a line number. It tells you where it is.

Comment: Does the compiler tell you the line numbers that those errors occur on? `int gcd(int,int);` is suspect

Comment: error starting from line number 5

Comment: And what **is** the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch the position of these two lines:

```
int main(void)

int gcd(int,int);
```

also, `elseif` -> `else if`

Comment: There's another crucial change required — move the `return` out of the loop in the GCD function.

Comment: That is a logic error, not a syntax error, which was the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The `gcd` function uses [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). It computes `a mod b`, then swaps `a` and `b` with an [XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

> [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738919/gcd-function-for-c)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int gcd(int ,int );


int main(void)
{
     int a,b, temp;
     printf("Enter the value of a : ");
     scanf("%d",&a);
     printf("Enter the value of b : ");
     scanf("%d",&b);

     int res = gcd(a,b);
     printf("The Gcd of the numbere is : %d \n",res);

     return 0;
}

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int temp;
    while (b != 0)
    {
        temp = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: You should explain the changes you've made.  The code looks plausibly correct (I've not compiled it), but you've not explained what you've done.  Explanation is the crucial part of an answer on SO.  Code alone is not sufficient to make a good answer — or, at least, it is almost never sufficient.

Comment: I explained as far as possible. :)

Comment: A link to an external source is not an explanation. And, you (and the link) do not explain what is wrong with OP's code, or what syntax errors exist there.